# What compiler tools are used by "official" language developers?

Tags: c#, java, compiler-construction, compilation

There are many lexical analyzer and parser generators out there - lex/flex and yacc/bison, jflex and javacup, gplex and gppg, etc.  I'm wondering what tools are used by the official developers of languages - do Sun and Microsoft use any of these in developing Java and .NET, or do shops of that size use only custom internal tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been inside a few commercial compilers, and I don't know of any that are built on lex or yacc generators.  Lex and yacc are handy to get a syntax up and parsing fairly quickly, but this is usually not the highest priority of a commercial product.  I'm not saying commercial products can't be built on yacc - I'm sure some have been - but the commercial compilers I've been part of have all been hand crafted code favoring raw speed over just about everything else.

And yes, compiling the compiler in itself is the norm, and a "fun" Escher-esque adventure in makefile logic. ;>

Comment: And crosscompiling mixed in with that makes it even funnier.

Answer (score 5):

I once heard a legend that most c compiler is compiled by itself.

What they do is that they write the new version (example version 5), compile it using the old version (version 4), then using the newly compiled version (version 5 that was compiled using version 4), they compile itself again. (so that version 5 is now compiled by version 5).

Comment: That is exactly how life on Earth started.

Comment: Not legend, this is exactly as it goes for years; see this classic 1984 article about compiling compilers: http://www.c-program.com/kt/reflections-on-trusting.html

Comment: I can't remember where i read it from. Ha ha. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @iWantSimpleLife   The chicken and egg problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29

Comment: I thought GCC was compiled by Pastel originally ? :-) Note such bootstrapping principles aren't limited to C compilers. Free Pascal works likewise, with the first version compiled by Turbo Pascal

Answer (score 0):

JavaCC has an up-to-date Java grammar. Whether the Java compiler is actually written via JavaCC is another question.

Comment: Grammars are often used as a form of documentation, and usually kept clean. Another such example is Delphi, which had a documentation in the inside cover of older versions, that is far, far from complete.

Answer (score 0):

For the more general purpose compilers, see D Thorpe's answer. They usually don't.

Such tools are however used by companies that routinely retarget usually C compilers to newly made targets(*), with target specific extensions, to quickly insert new features in a safe, consistent way, and then run some validation suite to ensure the result is compliant.

(*) Think of new DSPs, microcontrollers etc.